# conditional rendering with makeStyles() in MUI

Tags: javascript, css, reactjs, material-ui

In this code I tried to use `props.disabled` to dynamically change `backgroundColor` value under `"& + $track"` property, but MUI does not recognize it. Why is that?

```
const useStyles = makeStyles((theme) => ({
  root: {
    overflow: "visible",
    width: 36,
    height: 16,
    padding: 0,
    margin: theme.spacing(0.5),
    display: "flex",
  },
  switchBase: {
    padding: 2,
    color: theme.palette.grey[500],
    "&$checked": {
      transform: "translateX(18px)",
      color: theme.palette.common.white,
      "& + $track": {
        opacity: 1,
        backgroundColor: props => props.disabled ? theme.palette.grey[500] : theme.palette.primary.main,
        borderColor: theme.palette.primary.main,
      },
      "&:hover": {
        color: theme.palette.common.white,
      },
    },
    "&:hover": {
      color: theme.palette.primary.main,
    },
  },
  thumb: {
    width: 14,
    height: 14,
    boxShadow: "none",
  },
  track: {
    border: `1px solid ${theme.palette.grey[500]}`,
    borderRadius: 18 / 2,
    opacity: 1,
    backgroundColor: theme.palette.common.white,
  },
  checked: {
  },
}));

const StyledSwitch = (props) => {
  const classes = useStyles(props);
  return (
    <Switch
      classes={{
        root: classes.root,
        switchBase: classes.switchBase,
        input: classes.input,
        thumb: classes.thumb,
        track: classes.track,
        checked: classes.checked,
      }}
      {...props}
    />
  );
};
```

Comment: Please create a [code sandbox](https://codesandbox.io/s/new) reproducing your problem.

Answer (score 0):

You can't use props inside makeStyles as that is not available there.
Use the props.disabled var in JSX to conditionally apply a class and then define that class in makeStyles (define backgroundColor there).

Or use can use Mui-Disabled class (Pseudo-class applied to the internal SwitchBase component's disabled class)

```
"& + $track": {
    opacity: 1,
    backgroundColor: theme.palette.primary.main,
    borderColor: theme.palette.primary.main,
},    
"&.Mui-disabled + $track": {
    backgroundColor: theme.palette.grey[500],
},
```